# What is the use of NextJS API feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have seen Next JS API feature, it provides you the API folder where you can create API for frontend. But I am still confuse about few things.

1. Does it replace the need of backend e.g database and file handling etc
2. Is this for just sending you the response in JSON e.g mock service.

I am unable to understand the actual use case of this. I want to create full stack website. Frontend, backend, database, etc. Would this be possible with just Next JS?

Thank you.

I have tried some examples for returning the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use API routes as a replacement for a real backend with a server, if you want. They're serverless, located in one repo, and *so* much easier to manage. As for use cases, you can use API routes to process webhooks (for payments with Stripe, for example), fetch data from a database or external API, and the popular auth library NextAuth/Auth.js even uses API routes for its implementation. For a fullstack code example, check out the [Next.js Commerce starter kit](https://github.com/vercel/commerce), which uses API routes.

Comment: is there any limitation using the PHP or any other backend language over using next js? for using external api, integration i know this is will be good. how about stand alone app , means handling the data, user management all other things which a server language can do,, does it can do everything ? or is it good enough for the API only.

Answer (score 0):

Much recommend use BFF pattern with Next.js /api folder

[BFF - Backend for Frontend Design Pattern with Next.js - DEV Community](https://dev.to/adelhamad/bff-backend-for-frontend-design-pattern-with-nextjs-3od0)